# Do I have to add 'as' in 'It was (as) clear as water'?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Do I have to add 'as' in the following sentence?

> It was **(as)** clear as water

I ran a [search on ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20as%20clear%20as%20water%2Cwas%20clear%20as%20water&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20as%20clear%20as%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20clear%20as%20water%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwas%20as%20clear%20as%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20clear%20as%20water%3B%2Cc0) and didn't find much difference between the two options.

Comment: Useful sources: **1)** Scroll down to *Fixed expressions*: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis; **2)** https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73733/21520; **3)** Swan's *Practical English Usage*, 203.11: "We use the structure *as... as...* in a lot of traditional comparative expressions. 1. *as cold as ice* 2. *as black as night* 3. *as hard as nails*. The first *as* can be dropped in these expressions in an informal style. *She's hard as nails*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically *yes* - you are using a *simile*, and as you are comparing attributes you really need to say it is "*as* [x] *as* [y]". If you are finding examples where it has been omitted, these are probably just examples of colloquial speech where care has not been taken.

[Examples of similes](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-similes.html):

- As cute as a kitten
- As happy as a clam
- As light as a feather
- As blind as a bat
- As bold as brass

You could say instead:

> It was clear *like* water.